# How overload < and [] operatot on Python

Tags: python, oop

Recently OOP has moved from C++ to Python. I know the basics of the language more or less, but I had to work with OOP for the first time.

The task is as follows: "Create a class - real numbers, describe a field: a value of a real type. Define a constructor, functions for changing the field and getting its value, functions for dividing a number into integer and fractional parts, forming a real number from two integers corresponding to the integer and fractional parts ( in fixed-point format).Overload operations < (comparison of real numbers by the value of the integer part), [] (selection of the fractional part of the number).Sort the array of instances of the class of real numbers in descending order of the value of the integer part, programmatically check whether the numbers in the array will be ordered if fractional parts are taken into account.

Please, help me with the following points:
1)Overload operations < (comparison of real numbers by the value of the integer part), [] (selection of the fractional part of the number).
2)Sort the array of instances of the class of real numbers in descending order of the value of the integer part, programmatically check whether the numbers in the array will be ordered if fractional parts are taken into account

Thank you all in advance for your help.

Here is the code:

```
class Float(object):
def __init__(self, arg):    #constructor
    self.__arg = arg
    self.a = arg

@property                   #getter
def getarg(self):
    return self.__arg

def display_info(self):     #output results
    print(f"\nNumber: {self.__arg}")

def rozdel(self):           #division into integer and fractional parts
    self.a = int(self.__arg)
    self.b = self.__arg - int(self.__arg)
    print(f"\nInteger part: {self.a}, Fractional part: {self.b}")
    self.c = self.a + self.b
    print(f"\nПочаткове число: {self.c}")

def __lt__(self, other):    #overloading <
    return self.a < other.a

#------------------------------------------------------------------
def SortArr(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        min = i
        for j in range(i+1, len(arr)):
            if arr[j] < arr[min]:
                min = j
        arr[i], arr[min] = arr[min], arr[i]

#------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == '__main__':
    size = int(input("Enter count of elements: "))

    j = 0
    arr = []
    for i in range(size):
        j += 1
        print("---------------------")
        print("Variant %d" %(j))
        a = float(input("Enter rreal namber: "))
        arr.append(Float(a))
        arr[i].display_info()
        arr[i].rozdel()

SortArr(arr)
print("\n-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-")
print("After sorting:")
for i in range(size):
    print(str(arr[i]))
print("-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-\n")
```

Comment: Your question is too broad but start your research with what `__lt__` is

Comment: Hello again. Thanks for your advice. I rewrote the code a little and now sorting works. But now there is another problem. When sorting results are displayed, the knowledge I entered should be displayed, in sorted order.
They are displayed in sorted order, but instead of values, the following is displayed: <__main__.Float object at 0x0000022C0B178EB0>
<__main__.Float object at 0x0000022C0B178EE0>
<__main__.Float object at 0x0000022C0B178F10>

Comment: @Sollpix define [a `__repr__()` instance method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) that returns a string representation of the object - python will then use that when rendering the instance value as a string :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, I actually used `__str__()` method and it`s work, but thaank you for your advice. Maybe you(or anybody else too) can help me with this point: "overload [] operator (selection of the fractional part of the number)"